Is there any incentive for the 100 answerers to get the questions right?
In the gameshow Pointless, prior to the actual quiz, the questions are first asked to 100 people and the number of points scored are based on the how many of the 100 got it right. (The idea being to score as low as possible).
But is there an incentive for them to get the answer correct? It would matter in terms of the choice of answer by the actual contestant, especially for the easier questions
For example, an episode involved naming letters of the alphabet that scored more than 1 point in Scrabble. I would think that a common letter that people might expect to score 1 but doesn't is the ideal answer here (e.g. 'D')
However, the initial respondents don't really care if they get it right (or more importantly, not get it wrong) then that plan doesn't work as well because they could just name out any letters or even just list the entire alphabet, rather than avoiding the semi-common letters that they are not sure whether they score '1'.

They pay them and don't tell them that they're the Pointless survey.

Redshift Research, a London-based market research company has conducted all of the Pointless surveys online since the show began in 2009. They identify people to take part in a range of research surveys using their Crowdology online tool and pay them for the time they spend filling in questionnaires. The key thing, according to host Alexander Armstrong is that the people polled aren’t aware they’re answering Pointless questions. “You can’t ‘apply’ to be one of the 100 people because that would then affect the outcome.”
DenOfGeek - How do they choose the 100 people polled on Pointless?

As with most sample companies, they likely include trap questions to identify if people are just clicking buttons at random.

We reward our members fairly for taking part in market research,
providing they are absolutely honest. Our advanced systems are able to
identify multiple account entries and prevent duplicate participation
in surveys. We also undertake quality checks of completed surveys
before allocating rewards. Members who don’t abide by these basic,
simple rules run the risk of having their accounts deleted and
forfeiting their reward. This is made clear in our Terms & Conditions,
which you accept when you join us.
Survey Police - FAQ Crowdology


Interesting - then the answer would appear to be No.

@komodosp - The incentive is that you're trying to do a good job so that you get more surveys in future.

@komodosp You'd have to convincingly fake having a different body of knowledge to avoid the trap questions. There's no direct incentive to answer correctly, but there is an incentive to answer self-consistently, or else you might fail the QC and not get paid. You have a strong incentive to not answer randomly, and lesser incentive to not fake your answers (since you might do it "wrong") - for most people, the incentive structure makes the likelihood of payout highest if you generally answer as best you can.

Note that they're not demanding that you get the answer right, they're demanding that you tell them what you think
